# Get query string of Sharepoint URL from within SP2013 app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've got an app in sharepoint 2013, which is showing up inside of an iframe. I'd like to have links to the page that has the app embedded elsewhere, and pass data to my app through those links. Sounds like a job for query strings, right?

However, I can't find a way to get the query string in my app. None of the tokens I tried inserting had it, and I couldn't get it from within javascript because the url for my iframe and for sharepoint are different. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

if your app is within the SP page use

```
document.referrer
```

to get the full URL including query

Comment: That doesn't work because SP uses a redirect to end up on the app. So the referrer is a nonsense redirect.aspx page. I ended up having to change the domain for my app to be a subdomain of the main SharePoint site.